# Bootstrap have icon in the middle of column

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a section of website that has the left side of the row black and the right side red. Right smack in the middle I need to put a chevron from font awesome. The chevron sits on both the black and the red.

My code at the moment looks like:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="banner">
 <div class="row home">
  <div class="col-md-5 d-flex justify-content-end home-region-left align-items-center">
   <h2>Directions</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
  <%= fa_icon 'chevron-circle-right'%>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-5 d-flex justify-content-start home-region-right align-items-center">
  <%= form_tag zipcode_path, method: 'get', validate: true do%>
     <p><%=number_field :search, params[:search], required: true%>
        <%=submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-primary'
     </p>
  <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

This does not work. For starters the middle section takes up way too much space.

I've made several attempts but cannot figure out how to have an icon right smack in the middle. Here's my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jakewayne/aq9Laaew/252636/)

Comment: You want it to overlay the black and red?

Comment: can you show a picture of the output you are expecting? can't you just use % width for left, middle and right divs that sum up to 100% and play with those values? when you use col-md-X, it just sets a fixed % width depending on that value and floats the element. Use custom % values and you should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]
Use `position: absolute` and center the div in the middle:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row chevron">
    <div class="col left-side">
        Left
    </div>
    <div style="z-index: 1000; position: absolute; left: 50%; right: 50%; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: -10px; background: blue; width: 20px; text-align: center;">
      >
    </div>
    <div class="col right-side">
         Right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your updated fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/252649/).

Comment: This is nearly exactly what I am looking for.